# Setting up a custom linter in WebStorm (IntelliJ)

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, webstorm, vuetify.js

I am currently migrating from Vuetify 1.5x to 2.x, there is a linter which is supposed to help with the migration. [Here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/eslint-plugin-vuetify) I followed the guide but don't understand how to run the linter. When I try to configure WebStorm to use the linter I get this:
[image]

How can I get WebStorm to use this linter?

eslint.js:

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true
    },
    'extends': [
        'plugin:vue/essential',
        'eslint:recommended'
    ],
    rules: {
        'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
        'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
        'vuetify/no-deprecated-classes': 'error',
        'vuetify/grid-unknown-attributes': 'error',
        'vuetify/no-legacy-grid': 'error',

    },
    parserOptions: {
        parser: 'babel-eslint'
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "fibers": "^4.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.25.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.4.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.4.3"
  }
```

Settings in webstorm:
[image]

Comment: please share your `.eslintrc`, `package.json` and screenshot of *Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | ESLint* page

Answer (score 0):

Your settings are wrong. You have to specify the ESLint package (like `path/to/your/project/node_modules/eslint`), not its plugin as **EsLint Package:** value in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | ESLint**. It's ESLint that loads the plugin and lints your files, not the plugin itself